# Can you have multiple subclasses of MapActivity?

Tags: android, mapactivity

I know you can't have multiple instances in the same process, but is it at all possible to have multiple subclasses of MapActivity, so I don't have a lot of if-else statements and otherwise have overly huge classes?

And before anyone asks, I don't intend to have more than one instance of a MapActivity subclass running at the same time.

EDIT: Just for clarity's sake, I'm asking this because I'm concerned there might be subtle bugs due to having multiple subclasses. The same way there are *subtle* bugs with multiple instances of the MapActivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Although I think you want to have something like a BaseMapActivity that defines your common map related behaviour and extends from this instead of MapActivity?

Comment: That is a good idea; however, just to be certain, by yes do you mean there will no issues like there is in the case of multiple instances running at the same time?

Comment: I've had multiple Activities extend from a base class that extends from MapActivity without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can have multiple subclasses which extends and inherits from MapActivity if you want.

Creating multiple subclasses which inherits from MapActivity is like having lots of subclasses which are also inheriting from Activity.

Basically there's no difference at all.

Comment: The problem is not whether I can, but whether it will bugger up in some subtle way.